# How to get mod_jk.so/mod_jk.dll file for windows?

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing, httpd.conf, mod-jk

I am configuring httpd in windows server for load balancing. One of the step in configuration is to download tomcat connector for windows and put mod_jk.so file into modules folder. 
I downloaded latest connector of windows from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi

But after extracting, I could not find this file. I found some steps to build it on some sites, but those steps are of linux environments.

How to get mod_jk.so for windows environment ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011820/how-to-install-mod-jk-apache-tomcat-connectors-on-windows-server

Answer (score 0):

If you want `mod_jk` for Windows/httpd, then you should get it from the same place you got your binary distribution of `httpd`.

You probably got it from [ApacheLounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/), which BTW is not directly-affiliated with the Apache Software Foundation, but has been providing Windows binaries for quite some time and seems to be reputable. YMMV.