# unable to start apache httpd server with jk_module

Tags: java, tomcat7, mod-jk

My apache httpd server version is 2.4.
I am unable to start after I place `mod_jk` module in the modules folder.

I want to try load balancing tomcat instances with the mod_jk connector and for this purpose I have installed and set an apache httpd server which works fine.

But when I downloaded the `mod_jk` connector for 64 bit windows binary file which contains a file `isapi_redirect.dll` (which I take as the windows counterpart for mod_jk.so file for unix distributions) and placed it in the modules directory of the apache server and configured it in `httpd.conf` file the server fails to start and gives me following error:

`syntax error cant locate api module structure jk_module`

I need help as to how to set this up properly on windows with tomcat7

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41013011/3559908)?

Comment: yeah and i have done exaclty what the answer suggests but still it gives me that error also could'nt be the issue of 32bit and 64 bit since the connector used is 32 and 64 bit both

Comment: can someone comment that instead of mod_jk.so file iam getting a dll file with name isapi_redirect is this the correct file for windows version of tomcat connector for apache httpd server?

Comment: From the error message I would say that some path is not set correct. And did you also check the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156099/discussion-between-alex351-and-jlumietu) in the comments of the answer commented above? At the end there are some helpful instructions to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: ok @Vall0n ill see in the chat

Comment: @JayD `isapi_redirect.dll`is the connector built for Internet Information Server (IIS). If you are using `Apache` and not `IIS`, even in `Windows` you should use `mod_jk.so`, just as @vall0n suggested in the answer link he provided