# How to configure AJP between Apache in one server and Tomcat in another server

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, ajp

Hi I am new to AJP configuration. I have Apache configured with port 80 in one server and Tomcat with AJP 1.3 in another linux server where we deployed our war files. How to configure Apache to listen to Tomcat AJP in another linux server.
Apache redirection needed : /abc/def - So that when I hit URL http://server1/abc/def - it should load the page based on war file deployed in Server 2 Tomcat webapps

Server 1: Apache is running with Port 80
Server 2: Tomcat is running with Port 7000 and AJP in 7009

Comment: Do you want to configure mod_jk or mod_proxy?

Comment: I have apache in one Server and tomcat setup in four servers. So right now mod_jk is enabled.

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011820/how-to-install-mod-jk-apache-tomcat-connectors-on-windows-server

Comment: Sure let me try ... one quick question... which way is better mod jk or mod proxy !!!?

Comment: I have tried this setup ... it shows HTTP status 403 forbidden and mod jk logs it shows jk_handler::mod_jk.c No body with status=404 for worker

Comment: share Apache httpd configuration in question. Also let me know which URL are you using while access application directly through tomcat?